# Haskell Permute Function

Tags: algorithm, haskell, permutation, discrete-mathematics

This is my first question on this site. So if I am rude or not formal enough, I am sorry already.
In my discrete math class professor showed us this permute function

```
permute :: [a] -> [[a]]
permute [] = [[]]
permute xs = [y:zs| (y,ys) <- select xs, zs <- permute ys]

select :: [a] -> [(a,[a])]
select [] = []
select (x:xs) = (x,xs) : map(\(y,ys) ->(y,x:ys))(select xs)
```

I didn't understand  this part

```
permute xs = [y:zs| (y,ys) <- select xs, zs <- permute ys]
```

I tried `permute [1]` to understand clearly, in the first recursion `select xs` takes `[1]` and returns `[(1,[])]`.  Then `permute ys` takes `[]` if I am not mistaken.

In the second recursion, `select` takes `[]` and returns `[]` . I am lost somewhere here. As I see it, it should return `[[1],[]]` but it returns `[[1]]`.
I would be very happy if someone helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `permute [1]`, then `select [1]`, will return `[(1, [])]`, so that means that the list comprehension will take `y = 1` and `ys = []`. Then we call `permute []`, which returns `[[]]`. This thus means that `zs` will only take `zs = []`. We thus will yield `[ y : zs ]` which is equivalent to `[ 1 : [] ]`, and thus `[[]]`.

So since `zs <- permute []`, and thus is equivalent to `zs <- [[]]`, then this means that it only iterates *once* with `zs = []`.

If you `permute [1,2]` then we thus call `select [1,2]`, and this returns `[(1, [2]), (2, [1])]`. This thus means that in the list comprehension, `(y, ys)` will "iterate" twice: once with `y=1` and `ys=[2]`; and later with `y=2` and `ys=[1]`. For each value for `(y, ys)` it will then call `permute`. The `permute [1]` will return `[[1]]`, and `permute [2]` will return `[[2]]`. This thus means that we will return a list with: `[ 1 : [2], 2 : [1]]` which is thus equivalent to `[[1,2], [2,1]]`.